# How to hyphenate “small-gap short-period long devices”?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I would like to use a compound adjective for the word "devices", but I don't know how to place the hyphen. Does **small-gap short-period long devices** sound correct?

Comment: I would suggest adding commas between hyphenated adjectives, like "small-gap, short-period, long devices." It's hard for me to say if it looks or sound correct because I don't know the context.

Comment: Aren't 'short-period' and 'small-gap' more cohesive with the head noun than 'long'? 'Long' in what sense?

Comment: I've no idea what a "long device" is, but "short-period small-gap" (without comma and hyphenated like that) appears in [at least one paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8694390_Small-gap_insertion-device_development_at_the_National_Synchrotron_Light_Source_-_Performance_of_the_new_X13_mini-gap_undulator).

Comment: Ok. Let me clarify this. My device has a periodic mechanical structure along its length and this "period" is small. It also has a very small aperture (like a hole in the middle crossing his whole extension). And, the device is long, which means that compared to both gap and period its length is huge. Something like this (Sorry, I don't know how to add hyperlink here):
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/R%26D-TOWARDS-A-DELTA-TYPE-UNDULATOR-FOR-THE-LCLS*-Nuhn-Anderson/6695c644bb1bcfc1ee422f879c01280ab20f7cff/figure/1